# How to host a Rails application as an API that is only accessible locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, hosting, restful-authentication

I am starting to create a RESTful API that is built on Ruby on Rails. I would like my other applications (which are hosted on the same server) to be able to use this API. I had the idea that if the API is only available locally, I won't have to deal with the authentication logic since it won't be publicly accessible. I have never done this sort of thing before, so I don't even know if what I am asking for is possible (or if this is even a good idea).

How can I host this application so that my REST API is only locally accessible?

Comment: You could start your rails app on a different port like 8082 or something and then use firewall like iptables to prevent anyone from accessing the port externally, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Set the webserver to listen on loopback only

  - If you need to give access to the local network then configure your firewall to forward ports accordingly
- Set the webserver to listen only on the private network interface (not public)